# Axios Post Request with empty binary field form-data

Tags: node.js, axios, form-data, node.js-fs

i am trying to send an emtpy binary form-data request to an endpoint - with NODEJS. The field is required.

```
  data.append('picture1',fs.createReadStream('./example-images/image-1.jpg'));
  data.append('picture2', '');
  data.append('picture3', fs.createReadStream('./example-images/image-3.jpg'));


async function makeRequest(filename,data) {
      let config = {
        method: 'post',
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        url: 'URL ENDPOINT',
        headers: { 
          'Host': 'myhost.dot.net', 
          ...data.getHeaders()
        },
        data : data,
        responseType: "stream"
      };
      
      try {
       
        const response = await axios.request(config);
       
        const pdfContents = response.data;
}}
```

The request with Firefox works and looks.

`
-----------------------------1273980944350463539931767001
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Form1
-----------------------------1273980944350463539931767001
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture1"; filename="image-1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿá.......
-----------------------------1273980944350463539931767001
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture2"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

-----------------------------1273980944350463539931767001
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture3"; filename="image-3.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿá

-----------------------------1273980944350463539931767001--
`

Send Request with 3 pictures works, Send request with 2 pictures dont work.

any help who to send a empty binary form-data field?

Thx